# Making a div appear after the html video tag fullscreen

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styling

I have a very basic HTML video element in react

```
  <div class="d-flex flex-column">
          <video
            id="player"
            controls
          />
          <div >
            <p>make me visible even after fullscreen</p>
          </div>
  </div>
```

the thing is I want this div to appear after entering fullscreen by clicking on native html5 video element fullscreen control. I tried putting max z-index and making position absolute of the div element but it won't work after entering fullscreen. how can i solve this?

Comment: You can't. Because then the Video wouldn't be fullscreen anymore. Fullscreen is controlled by browser and not by site creator.

Comment: Okay thanks for the answer ^_^